# c++ Weird linker error happens when passing some arguments to a template

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, linker

I have been trying to implement std::vector on my own. And I come across this weird linker problem, which occurs when I pass some arguments to the template . When passed with some other arguments, the code works just fine. I am really confused what goes wrong here, and don't know what keyword I can use to google with. The problem description goes as follows:

```
//vector.hpp: all the following is inside namespace wyf
template<typename Tp, typename Allocator = std::allocator<Tp>>
class vector {
public:
    using value_type = Tp;
    using allocator_type = Allocator;
    using size_type = std::size_t;
    using difference_type = std::ptrdiff_t;
    using reference = value_type&;
    using const_reference = const value_type&;
    using pointer = typename std::allocator_traits<Allocator>::pointer;
    using const_pointer = typename std::allocator_traits<Allocator>::const_pointer;
// linker error occurs when calling this ctor with certain arguments
    vector(size_type n, const_reference val, const allocator_type& alloc = allocator_type());
// other ctors
    vector() : begin_(nullptr), end_(nullptr), capacity_() { }
    vector(size_type n, const_reference val, const allocator_type& alloc = allocator_type());
    explicit vector(size_type n);
    template<typename IterTp> 
      vector(IterTp beg_, IterTp end_, const allocator_type& alloc = allocator_type());
    vector(const vector& other, const allocator_type& alloc = allocator_type());
    vector(vector&& other);
    vector(vector&& other, const allocator_type& alloc);
    vector(std::initializer_list<value_type> init_list, const allocator_type& alloc = allocator_type());
// omitting other member functions.
private: // three data members to hold the objects and raw memory
    pointer begin_; // using pointer = value_type*;
    pointer end_;
// Empty Base Optimization Helper class to hold both Allocator and capacity_
    EmptyBaseOptimizationHelper<allocator_type> capacity_; 
}
// still in vector.hpp, the implemention goes below
template<typename Tp, typename Allocator> 
vector<Tp, Allocator>::vector(std::size_t n, const Tp& val, const Allocator& alloc) :
begin_(nullptr), end_(nullptr), capacity_(nullptr, alloc) {
  begin_ = (get a pointer to allocator)->allocate(n*2);// allocate raw memory
  end_ = begin_ + n;
  capacity_.capacity_ = begin_ + n*2; 
  for (auto p = begin_; p != end_;) 
    (get a pointer to allocator)->construct(p++, val);
 }
```

That's all for vector.hpp.(I used some pseudocode to make it more readable). When I do some testing, the weird linker error present itself.

```
#include "vector.hpp"
int main() { 
  wyf::vector<int> v2(10, 20);
}
```

When I compile with g++/clang++, the following linker error pops up:

```
vector.cc:(.text+0x66): undefined reference to `wyf::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >::vector<int>(int, int, std::allocator<int> const&)'
```

It seems that wyf::vector v2(10, 20); is regarded as calling a ctor with signature wyf::vector(int, int, std::allocator const&). But what I declared and implemented is wyf::vector(std::size_t, const int&, std::allocator const&). The linker is designed to fail when I try to link something that I didn't actually implement. Hence the linker error.
With these in mind, I tried the following call

```
wyf::vector<int> v3(static_cast<std::size_t>(10), 20);
```

And it worked just fine. Moreover, I find that, as long as I pass arguments that will trigger a conversion(implicit or explicit), the linker won't complain at all:

```
wyf::vector<int> v4(10.0, 20);
wyf::vector<int> v5(10, 20.0);
```

The code above compile and link with no error. I am really confused here. Can anyone tell me why all these happen and what I can do to make wyf::vector v(10, 20) work as expected.

Comment: "all the following is inside namespace wyf" Please post all code, rather that comments explaining what's in omitted code. Also please indent your code.

Comment: Which compiler do you use? You have for some reason disabled implicit conversions. The literal `10` you are passing to constructor is type `int` it is normal, than implicit conversion should apply to `std::size_t`. To be honest i use GCC and i don't even  know if it's possible to disable implicit conversion, i was looking for it for ages.

Comment: It [does not reproduce](http://ideone.com/rkhQqI) when coerced to a compilable form. Construct a [mcve].

Comment: @n.m. Sorry, the entire code is too long to display.  About 500 lines.

Comment: @Radek I use gcc. I haven't disabled implicit conversions. Or wyf::vector v4(10,0, 20) couldn't have worked.

Comment: It's your job to reduce it to a form that can be shown to strangers on the Internet.

Comment: If the entire code is too long, then produce a smaller sample that exhibits the same problem.   Do that by progressively removing code that is not relevant    But don't rely on your guesses to work out what is relevant - if you don't know what the problem is, odds are you'll cut out something relevant.   Remove a bit, compile to see if it exhibits the same problem, etc.

Comment: Heh, after edit, i see you have more constructors in the class. This you should mention at the beginning. The most important information.

Comment: @Radek At the beginning, I didn't think other constructors are relevant. But when I reviewed my code to reproduce the problem as n.m. asked, I found that I was not thinking in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I was trying to reproduce the problem, I found out where the problem is. 
The problem here is **constructor overload resolution** chooses a constructor have not implemented yet.

```
wyf::vector<int> v1(10, 20);
```

The call above is supposed to call the following constructor through a implicit conversion from int to size_type(std::size_t) conducted on 10:

```
vector(size_type n, const_reference val, const allocator_type& alloc = allocator_type());
```

But instead, compiler sees a better match, and chooses:

```
template<typename IterTp> 
vector(IterTp beg_, IterTp end_, const allocator_type& alloc = allocator_type());
```

and instantiates wyf::vector (int, int, const std::allocator&) with IterTp being int. Since I have not implemented that constructor yet, the code compiles but fail to link. The following code succeeds to link:

```
wyf::vector<int> v3(static_cast<std::size_t>(10), 20);
wyf::vector<int> v4(10.0, 20);
wyf::vector<int> v5(10, 20.0);
```

becasue the 2 aurguments are of two different types. So the compiler cannot deduce the type of IterTp for the template version constructor, and the non-template version is chosen, which is the code works as I expected.